# FolderBrowserDialog C# SelectedPath always displayed at bottom

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog

im opening a FolderBrowserDialog the following way:

```
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbd.Description = desc;
        fbd.SelectedPath = defaultPath;
        fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = showNewFolderButton;
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            return fbd.SelectedPath + @"\";
        else
            return "";
```

This works. But every time i select a new folder in this dialog the whole "Folder-Tree" scrolls down to the bottom so that the selected folder is at the bottom of the FolderBrowserDialog. That gets pretty annoying cuz i always have to scroll down again to select another folder...

Any solution for this?

Thx!

Comment: You want to create new folder without focusing to it?

Comment: No. I want to select a specific folder and this selected folder has to stay where i selected it. but in my case the list of folders is scrolling down (without me doing it) so that i cant select the folder inside me previously selected folder

Comment: i just saw that when i select the folder by its name the list of folders scrolls automatically. when i click on the little triangle next to the name the list doesnt move.....wired?!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue..

Comment: Which operating system? I think it might be a Windows 7 (maybe also Vista?) related issue as the explorer on these operating system quite often behaves in a similar way when selecting a folder from the tree view in the left hand pane (I, btw. don't like that behaviour, but maybe I'm just too used to XP).

Comment: No idea what the problem actually is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce what you are see in Windows 7. This happens only the first time around though. So if you compress the expanded folder and try again clicking on it, it doesn't move  the selected folder down but stays where it is and expands the subfolders under it. This doesn't happen if we use the arrow cursor to expand the folder. Sometimes I see that the selected folder even moves up so as to show all the contents. It might be by design or a minor bug.